# how to pass data from woocommerce cart item to order item?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Using '**before_checkout**' hook , im doing some calculations with the cart item data which is before payment. I need to send those data to order item meta in another hook like '**woocommerce_thankyou**' after payment is done.

Is there a way to *relate the cart items and its corresponding order* which is created?

Answer (score 4):

There is hook for add item meta for to be add to order so you can relate cart items and its corrosponding order:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'add_order_item_meta_after_order', 10, 3);
function add_order_item_meta_after_order($item_id, $values, $cart_item_key) {       
    wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, '_your_key_in_order', $values, true);
}
```

May be useful to you.

Comment: There is just a missing 's' at $value otherwise it works just fine, many thanks!

Comment: @user1875631:and Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can use to get the cart items in the order 'woocommerce_thankyou' hook.

```
global $woocommerce;
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ($items as $pid) {
   $product_ids = $pid['product_id']; // and so on
}
```